# Why if I unset an alias in Git , it is still working?

Tags: git

I have made an alias as follow: `git config --global alias.s status`, and then I wanted to cancel it by doing `git config --global --unset alias.s`

When I check with `git config --global --edit` the alias is not there anymore but if I do `git s` it is still working as git status.

Do you know why? Normally I unset it, it should not work anymore no?

Comment: Try leaving out --global ... maybe it was set in 2 places

Comment: Yes indeed it works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases, like other Git config, can be set both locally (without `--global` and globally (with `--global`). Check local config with `git config --edit` and use `--unset` without `--global` to unset local config.